# How to convert VTKMolecule to Polydata?

Tags: vtk

I found this class `vtkMoleculeToPolyDataFilter`, but don't know if I was being blind as I could not find any method that takes vtkMolecule as input in this class. Does anyone know how can I do the conversion between them, thanks for the help.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> FilteringEvent::Molecule_To_PolyData(const vtkSmartPointer<vtkMolecule> &Molecule) {
     mMoleculeToPolyDataFilter->SetInputData(Molecule);
     mMoleculeToPolyDataFilter->Update();
     return  mMoleculeToPolyDataFilter->GetOutput();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code around ?

Comment: Yeah, I have uploaded my code. The problem is when I try to use the "SetInputData" method to establish the pipeline, it only takes vtkDataobject type and its derived classes as an argument, not VTKMolecule , So I am not sure how to set the VTKMolecule as input data of this filter class @ Nico Vuaille

Comment: [vtkMolecule](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkMolecule.html) inherits from `vtkDataObject`, so your code is valid. Do you have an error ?

Comment: no worry, I figured out the problem, I didn't notice the "vtkMoleculeToPolyDataFilter" is an abstract class, so I couldn't instantiate it.  I need to use the subclass of it to establish the pipeline. thanks anyway! @Nico Vuaille

Comment: Ah, indeed. Also note there already are [3 subclasses](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkMoleculeToPolyDataFilter.html). `AtomBall'  and `BondStick` create geometry, i.e. you will get triangulated spheres and tubes, whereas `MoleculeToLine` only create one point per atom and one cell per bond.

Comment: (and do not hesitate to answer your own question to mark this thread as resolved !)

Answer (score 1):

Because the vtkMoleculeToPolyDataFilter is an abstract class,  so one of its subclasses is needed to do the conversion.
For more info-- AtomBall'  and BondStick` create geometry, i.e. you will get triangulated spheres and tubes, whereas MoleculeToLine only creates one point per atom and one cell per bond.